# Spacing issue with image placed in table - HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm building a table for my website, and I'm trying to place a logo inside of a data cell. The issue is that whenever I add the picture, the margins go really weird and I can't figure out why spacing is added. I tried to remove the padding and margins on the image, and the cell itself, but nothing fixes it.

Before image:

[image]

After image:

[image]

HTML:

```
<table class="table">
            <thead class="tablehead">
                <tr>
                    <th>Language</th>
                    <th>Year Initiated</th>
                    <th>Projects</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="tablebody">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src = "images/Java_Logo.png" class="tableimage"></td>
                    <td>2015</td>
                    <td>ENTER LINK</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>C#</td>
                    <td>2016</td>
                    <td>ENTER LINK</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Python</td>
                    <td>2018</td>
                    <td>ENTER LINK</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HTML and CSS</td>
                    <td>2018</td>
                    <td>ENTER LINK</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

CSS:

```
    .table{

    margin: auto;

}

.tablehead{

    font-family: permanent marker;
    font-size: 24px;

}

.tablebody{

    font-family: body;
    font-size: 20px;

}

.tableimage{

    width: 15%;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;

}

th, td{

    border-bottom: 1px rgb(146, 40, 40) solid;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;

}
```

I've also already tried multiple different images, so this does not seem to be the issue. I'd like all three columns to take up 1/3 of the space each.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The row expands to the height of the image. Do you want to shrink the image so that the row is the same size it was before, or do you want to enlarge the other three rows so they match the new size of the Java row?

Comment: I'd like to shrink the cell the image is in to match the other two columns. When I use inspect element in a browser, the picture takes up a small rectangle, with a large space to the right of it that I want to get rid of. I just don't know why the space is there, it doesn't seem to be a margin or padding that I've set.

Comment: Oh, you mean the horizontal space. I was merely looking at vertical space. That makes sense; I see that now :) Though running your code doesn't cause the same issue for me -- the problem must lie outside of the HTML / CSS you have provided. Are you using any frameworks or anything?

Comment: No frameworks or anything else, just barebones html and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to specify a width for the table cells. Try adding this to your CSS:

```css
th, td {
    width: 33%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use this, which changes the behavior of the table overall. (Set your preferred width, or nothing at all):

```
table {table-layout: fixed; width: 50%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The table must some other css affecting it. When I put your code into JSFiddle, it seems to work the way you want. See example: https://jsfiddle.net/ruben/xg2joc1y/5/

You could try adding some css to your image:

```
.table img {
  display: inline;
}
```